# Refresh Data in CollectionView in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, reload

I have an odd dilemma where when I reload the data in my `collectionview` all of the stylings in my collectionviewcells are out of order. I have a button where I reload the data using

```
    @IBAction func pokePreviousIBO(_ sender: Any) {
    monsters = monPrevious
    displayDataForIndexPath()
    self.dCollectionViewIBO.reloadData()

}
```

**EDIT:** After doing some research it seems that the issue is coming from the fact that I need to remove the data from the CollectionView before reloading. How do I achieve this using Swift? The data I'm using is from a model with the values segued from the previous view controller

```
let monsters: Monsters
```

Comment: Show the collection view datasource methods.

Comment: if your `UICollectionView` loads different data every time it is reloaded check your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, your might have used `Dictionary`(?) or some random values to populate your cell.